# C - main() command line parameters

Tags: c, command-line, parameters, program-entry-point

This is a really basic question but I can't find a definitive answer anywhere.
I understand the parameters of main, as far as what they refer to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

where argc refers to the number of command line arguments and argv refers to the array that holds each of the strings.  I created an exe file of the source code from the .c file, but have no experience with command prompts and don't understand the syntax of the command line arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *infile, *outfile;
    int iochar;

    if(argc != 3){
        printf("Usage: filename infile outfile\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((infile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't open input file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't open output file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((iochar = getc(infile))!=EOF){
        putc(iochar, outfile);
    }

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);

    printf("You've reached the end of the program.\n"); 

    return;
}
```

The preceding code should take 3 arguments and copy the 2nd argument's contents into the 3rd argument's location.  What do I have to do for this to happen?

Comment: You appear to be asking two questions here, which do not appear to be related. And the first - "where are each of these arguments stored" - doesn't make any sense. They're provided as arguments to the function `main()`.

Comment: To understand what's going on here, first set a breakpoint on the `if(argc != 3)` line, then examine the contents of `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: @sudowned I guess a better of phrasing it is how do I supply the argument to the command prompt?  I can't ever seem to get to a point where the command prompt accepts any input.

Comment: You don't execute or run the .c file. That's your source code. You need to compile it into an executable first.

Comment: @John The program always exits on the if(argc != 3) line because the I see the following print statement.  So effectively there are argc and argv don't assume any values because nothing was ever input.

Comment: @Aleyha, It is my understanding that your program exits *after* the `if(argc != 3)` line, so you should be able to set a breakpoint on that line and it should get hit.

Comment: I think I figured out what was going on.  I needed to build an executable file of my C source code.  Then I needed to open a command prompt, and type 3 arguments starting with the location of the exe file.  I was originally trying to just debug the source code, since I've never actually built the .c file into an .exe before.  And sorry, I wasn't sure what you meant by breakpoint.  My experience with C is very lacking to be sure.

Comment: @If you're using Visual Studio, you don't need to open a command prompt. Just build your program (F7), then run it (F5), after setting the command line in your project's Debug properties (per my answer below).

Comment: `printf("Can't open input file.\n");` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Which file?  Why can you not open it?  Why is the error message being printed to stdout instead of stderr? Replace that horrible line of code with `perror( argv[1] )`, and make a similar replacement for all the other error messages.

Comment: The code was transcribed from my book but I see your point, thank you.  About to learn the difference between the different standard streams.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the command line arguments in the Debug properties of your VS project.

> don't understand the syntax of the command line arguments.

The details of the syntax of the command line arguments depends on what program is interpreting them ... VS, a Windows shortcut, Windows cmd, bash, etc. ... but generally it's just a list of items separated by spaces. If the items themselves contain spaces, quotes, or other special characters, then you need to pay attention to the rules of the interpreter you're using.

The semantics of the command line arguments is defined by your program ... in this case, the first argument is the name of the input file and the second argument is the name of the output file.

```
printf("Usage: filename infile outfile\n");
```

This is not a good usage message ... the "filename" should be the name of your program, which is generally the value of argv[0]. Thus:

```
printf("Usage: %s infile outfile\n", argv[0]);
```

Comment: So technically the first argument is the phrase AFTER the location of the program?  Or is the location of the program considered the first argument?

Comment: @Aleyha The former. The first argument is infile, the second argument is outfile. Although the program path is in argv (argv[0]), it is not considered or called an argument.

Comment: @Aleyha Yes, argc is the number of elements in argv, not including the terminating NULL. In your case argc would be 3.

Comment: And one last question, sorry to bother.  I tried to set the solution explorer -> properties -> debugging -> command arguments to 3 (or is that 2 if that's how VS 2012 interprets arguments?).  This still doesn't bring up the command prompt for me though.  Did you mean something else by setting command line the project's debug Properties?

Comment: @Aleyha You want 2 arguments -- the actual arguments, not a number. Then hit F5 and your program should run, copy the file, and exit ... there won't be any command prompt. You can set a breakpoint at the beginning of the program (double click the margin of the first if statement and you should get a red circle) and it will stop there and you can step through the program. I urge you to read the VS help to become familiar with it -- it's quite powerful and will help you later. (Note: I mostly work on GUI programs in VS, not console apps, so my comments here may be off a little.)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  New to VS/2012/C programming in that order, and this was sort of the last topic that was fairly superficially covered.